# Combine objects and remove interior faces?

Tags: modeling, objects

I want to start off by saying I am in no way a blender genius. I have about a year of diddle dawdling myself around and following a couple of tutorials. Today, me my ADHD self and I, decided to recreate my logo in 3D! Yay! And I got pretty far. I designed the shapes, lighting is a B, but I got a somewhat decent result for my purpose of staring at it when I am bored. But then... ADHD me wanted more. I needed more! I wanted frosted glass instead of black nothingness for the features! This is not a biggie as I have followed a couple of tutorials for this but then I cam across this problem.
[image: problem]
Now I don't know about you, but whenever I see glass, it does not have funky planes visible! I made the general long line first and then the 'teeth' of the mouth, then I shift clicked them all and used
`ctrl + J`
to join them. The problem with this is the shapes didn't become one solid object, they became a bunch of intersecting 3D items that look terrible with 3D. This is in edit mode (yes I know my modelling skills are not up to par, I am a self taught teen leave me alone):
[image: problem, but in edit mode]
How can I combine the shapes in a way that deletes the interior faces and makes the intersections create vertices? Thank you all who can help or point out my stupidity.

EDIT:
While waiting, I started to mess around with object modifiers as I realized they work with joined objects. I used the remesh mod to generally fix the inside, but now the object is kind of squiggly. This  is a work around for now, but any real answers are appreciated.

Comment: Could try using booleans

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that if you were to separate all the parts of the mesh with P, then you could use the boolean modifiers union mode to better connect them. Or you could also use loop cuts to create support geometry and merge the intersections together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get rid of those inside faces, is to manually delete them...

Go to wireframe, and when u start doing it, make sure you're not deleting faces u want to stay... But in case u delete something by accident, select the vertices of the hole/empty face, and click F to fill it with a new face :)

Now, for merging faces together, u need to merge the vertices. U can do this by selecting both vertices u wanna connect, then press on your keyboard Alt+M, then click "At Center"

If u don't understand much of what I'm talking about, then search up for some tutorials about merging faces/objects and topology in YouTube

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Note that you can select all interor faces in a mesh by going Select > Select all by trait > Interior faces